# Highstock data input with csvURL only allows a limited number of rows

Tags: csv, highcharts

I want to import data in a highstock chart per csvURL and the chart works fine up to 250 rows: https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/qx6gad34/1/

```
   data: {
        csvURL: 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/FSE/VOW3_X.csv?api_key=FaKetdwzkQQPhX91Xrhx',
        switchRowsAndColumns: false,
        firstRowAsNames: true,
        startRow: 0,
        endRow: 250,
        seriesMapping: [{
              x: 0,
              y: 4
              },
              {},
              {},
              {}]
        }
```

When I increase the number of rows, nothing is displayed: https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/qx6gad34/4/

How can I show the total number of rows from the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both charts you have `Highcharts error #15`:

> **Highcharts expects data to be sorted**
>
> This happens when creating a line
>   series or a stock chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X
>   order.
>
> For performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it
>   requires that the implementer pre-sorts the data.

The difference is that in the second chart `cropThreshold` property is exceeded and that is why the series is not displayed.

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.cropThreshold

Comment: Thank you, I added a higher number for cropThreshold in the plotOptions but did not get the wanted result: https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/qx6gad34/5/

Is there a way to avoid error #15. I can´t change the data. But the original data is sorted, unfortunately the other way around, starting with the newest date.

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, You can reverse your data on frontend. For example in `parsed` function: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8pyt41v9/

Comment: Thank you! That helped.